# Getting Error while deploying to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

`Unable to locate the JVM for project scrapbook1. Please verify that you have a project-level JVM installed by inspecting your project's build path.`

I get this error in the console when i debug my web application in Eclipse 
Please help !!!

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed JVM/JDK? Assuming you are on Windows, go to command prompt and type

```
set %JAVA_HOME%
```

This should the path to JDK. If it does not, then you need to install JDK and set the parameter JAVA_HOME in environment variables.

Once you have installed JDK and set the variable, check following: Go to Java build path of your project (Hit Alt+Enter on your project) and see if it shows JRE system library as shown in image:

[image]

Comment: i downloaded the JDK and set the System Environment variable when i type `set %JAVA_HOME%` in the CMD i get the following output `Environment variable C:\Program Files\Java\jre6 not defined ` really worried how to go about pla help !!!

Comment: So basically you dont have proper JDK Setup! Don't worry, if you start worrying abt these things, how you will make big? Start from http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Install_a_JVM

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the JDK was installed. I just updated all the libraries 'Help -> Check for Updates' and then restarted Eclipse. After that, everything worked.